# Identify underlying OS in bash on windows

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a simple way to determine if bash is running on Windows? Running `uname` gives "Linux" which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally tested this but `if [ -d /mnt/C ]` may work.

This is probably a terrible solution

Comment: It works because usually Windows has a "C:" drive and in the Ubuntu on Windows, /mnt/C refers to that drive.

Comment: This is essentially a code-only answer, that's not very helpful in understanding the solution. It promotes cargo-cult programming, and does a lousy job putting the reader in a position to make an educated decision, whether this may or may not solve their problem. Please update your answer.